# Which commit should be used when deploy gnosis safe to a new network

Tags: gnosis-safe, network

I will deploy gonsis safe(https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts) to a new network. Shall I use the lastest commit, or use the lastest release(current version is v1.3.0-libs.0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the Readme it is recommended to use the latest release (v1.3.0-libs.0): https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts#deploy